# Nested optimization in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I wrote a short snippet to train a classification model, and learn the learning rate of its optimization algorithm. In my example I tried to update weights of a network in an inner optimization loop and to learn the learning rate of the weight updates using an outer optimization loop (meta-optimization). I'm getting the error:

> RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [3, 10]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 12; expected version 2 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).

My code snippet is as following (NOTE: I'm using `_stateless`, an experimental functional API for `nn`. You need to run with the nightly build of pytorch.)

```py
import torch
from torch import nn, optim
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

from torch.nn.utils import _stateless


class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.N = N
        self.x = torch.rand(self.N, 10)
        self.y = torch.randint(0, 3, (self.N,))

    def __len__(self):
        return self.N

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.x[idx], self.y[idx]


class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10, 10)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10, 3)

        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

        self.alpha = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1))
        self.beta = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1))

    def forward(self, x):
        y = self.relu(self.fc1(x))
        return self.fc2(y)

epochs = 20
N = 100
dataset = DataLoader(dataset=MyDataset(N), batch_size=10)
model = MyModel()
loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optim = optim.Adam([model.alpha], lr=1e-3)

params = dict(model.named_parameters())
for i in range(epochs):
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0
    for batch_idx, (x, y) in enumerate(dataset):
        logits = _stateless.functional_call(model, params, x)             # predict
        loss_inner = loss_func(logits, y)                                 # loss
        optim.zero_grad()                                                 # reset grad
        loss_inner.backward(create_graph=True, inputs=params.values())    # compute grad
        train_loss += loss_inner.item()                                   # store loss
        for k, p in params.items():
            if k is not 'alpha' and k is not 'beta':
                p.update = - model.alpha * p.grad
                params[k] = p + p.update                      # update weight

    print('Train Epoch: {}\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(i, train_loss / N))
    logits = _stateless.functional_call(model, params, x)                 # predict
    loss_meta = loss_func(logits, y)
    loss_meta.backward()
    loss_meta.step()
```

From the error message, I understand that the issue comes from weight update for the weights of the second layer of the network, which points to an error in my inner loop optimization. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This discussion may serve https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/get-the-best-learning-rate-automatically/58269/3.

Answer (score 0):

Check this  link and save PARAMs per each epoch and use same inner batch:
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/issue-using-parameters-internal-method/134549/11

```
for i in range(epochs):
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0
    params = dict(model.named_parameters()) # add this
    for batch_idx, (x, y) in enumerate(dataset):
        params = {k: v.clone() for k,v in params.items()} # add this
        logits = _stateless.functional_call(model, params, x)             # predict
        loss_inner = loss_func(logits, y)
        ..................
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be updating `params[k].data` instead of `params[k]`

(Deleted the example to avoid distraction)

Let me enter in a kind of fundamental discussion (not an answer to your question).

If I undertand correctly you want to compute  `loss(f(w[i], x))` , and computing the  `w[i+1,j] = w[i,j] + g(v[j], w[i,j].grad(w.r.t loss))` . Then in the end you want to compute `v[j+1] = v[j] + v[j].grad(w.r.t loss)`.

The gradient of `v[j]` is computed using the backward propagation, as a function of grad `w[i,j]`. So what you are trying to do is to choose `v[j]` that results in a good `w[i,j]`. I would ask: why would you bother about `v[j]` if you can control `w[i,j]` directly? And that's what the standard approach.

Comment: This is not correct as it is not updating the learning rate for the inner optimization at all. You can plot the computational graph using `make_dot(logits, params=dict(list(model.named_parameters()))).render('comp_graph_beta', format='png')` after line 66 and see `model.alpha` is not present in the graph. (use `from torchviz import make_dot`)

Comment: Yes, you define alpha but you don't use in your model or in the loss function. What do you expect, alpha should multiply the learning rate?

Comment: In that case you have to create a new set of parameters each iteration and and the outer optimization will see very deep neural netwoork. Prone to gradient explosion/vanishing, also, I am not sure that gradient descent method is a good approach to optimize a 1-D Parameter space.

Comment: I do use it in my model, it's the learning rate of the inner optimization algorithm. Note that my model in the inner loop is `MyModel`, in the outer loop it is `MyModel` + the inner loop updates. So any parameters introduced in the inner loop would be optimized in the outer loop. If I update `params[k].data` as you suggested, `model.alpha` will never be introduced to the model. Think about it this way: when you do `loss_meta.backward()`, the outer optimization model should see `model.alpha` as a parameter, so it should in fact update `params[k]`.

Comment: It is true that in this case it is a 1-D parameter space, but this is only a toy example. But, why do you think that it is prone to gradient explosion/vanishing?

Comment: Just intuition. I think in it as a dynamic system, if it was a linear system it would have an exponential behavior, growing exponential lead to gradient explosion, shrinking exponnetials lead to gradient vanishng.

Comment: But for high dimensional spaces it might make sense.

Comment: Makes sense. Let me also ask what optimization method would you suggest for a 1-D space?

Comment: A simple sweep. The step size normalization such as momentum, damping will give much more benefit than the choice of the learning rate. Learning rate scheduling might help as well. The idea behind learning rate scheduling is quite similar to simulated annealing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238617/discussion-between-bob-and-blade).