# Issue using ._parameters internal method in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to access model parameters using the internal `._parameters` method. When I define the model as below, I get model parameters without any issue

```
model = nn.Linear(10, 10)
print(model._parameters)
```

However, when I use this method to get parameters of a model defined as a class, I get an empty `OrderedDict()`.

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(10, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.fc(x)

model = MyModel()
print(model._parameters)
```

Is there a solution to this using `._parameters`?

NOTE: I understand that using internal methods are frowned upon.

Comment: So you are well aware that its an internal thing. Then why using it ? What exactly you are trying to do with `._parameters` ?

Comment: Why are you using `_parameter` after all?

Comment: @Ivan Working on differentiable pytorch optimizers.

Comment: @Ivan One example is to develop an optimizer for the inner-loop optimization in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69589474/nested-optimization-in-pytorch

Comment: Why not use `nn.Module.parameters` instead? See my edit below.

Comment: @Ivan Asking why not use `nn.Module.parameters` is one thing, writing it as *However, it seems you don't care much* is another thing. The latter one is rather bizarre, to say the least. Assuming that this is rather a misunderstanding on my side, pytorch optimizers are currently not differentiable. If you write your own optimization class (in the form of `class MyOptimizer(torch.optim.Optimizer)`), directly accessing the weight memory location is the way to go. [Example](https://github.com/learnables/learn2learn/blob/ad0ffc1b85d4d08706eb592f78eca3f2c61f3360/learn2learn/utils/__init__.py#L227).

Comment: Apologies for my comment, I have removed it. `nn.Module.parameters` does give you access to the weight underlying memory. The underlying implementation of this function is accessing the child module's `_parameters` recursively. That is why it is recommended to use this API instead of fetching the parameters by hand. Apologies again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each linear layer in the `MyModel` class is a module, and can be accessed using `_modules`. So you can access the parameters of your model using:

```
for module_key in model._modules.keys():
    for param_key in model._modules[module_key]._parameters:

        p = model._modules[module_key]._parameters[param_key]
```

Comment: I don't see the point of doing so when there is a builtin [`nn.Module.parameters`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=parameters#torch.nn.Module.parameters) function. Most importantly your code will will fail in cases where the modules have submodules themselves... `nn.Module` is a recursive object architecture.

Comment: @Ivan I believe that since the question states "Is there a solution to this using `._parameters`", the first part of your comment should be directed to the OP. On the second part, OP has provided his/her model and I'm answering based on the provided model, not hypothetical situations.

Comment: If you think this is an acceptable question to give - regardless of the OP's intent or constraints - then I disagree with you. Providing an alternative solution that fits with the OP's needs and is in line with the best practices would be preferred. The solution you have provided has two shortcomings: **(a)** it won't work in a general case, and **(b)** goes against PyTorch API and design. Anyhow, that's all from me, I won't bother you any longer ;).

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of objects in an [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html): tensors stored inside [`_parameters`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7191dd2613051b1ddfe7f5a9cfd0397b1444a116/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L257), buffers inside [`_buffers`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7191dd2613051b1ddfe7f5a9cfd0397b1444a116/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L258), and modules inside [`_modules`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7191dd2613051b1ddfe7f5a9cfd0397b1444a116/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L266). All three are private (indicated by the `_` prefix), as such they are not meant to be used by the end-user.

The *private* `nn.Module` attribute `_parameters` is an *OrderedDict* containing parameters of the module ("parameters" as in `nn.Parameter`s, not `nn.Module`s). That is the reason why it is empty in your example. Have a look at the following module instead:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.p = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(10))

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.fc(x)

>>> model = MyModel()

>>> print(model._parameters)
OrderedDict([('p', Parameter containing:
tensor([8.5576e-01, 1.4343e-01, 3.2866e-04, 9.4876e-01, 4.4837e-01, 9.7725e-02,
        2.7249e-01, 6.7258e-01, 5.6823e-01, 4.0484e-01], requires_grad=True))])
```

---

> I understand that using internal methods are frowned upon.

**Do not use `_parameters`**. You should instead use the appropriate API for this use case, which is [`nn.Module.parameters`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=parameters#torch.nn.Module.parameters):

```
for p in model.parameters():
    print(p)
```